# How to write generic partialCall function which consume tail parameters?

Tags: typescript, generics

The partialCall example from [variadic types](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-0/#variadic-tuple-types) 'consumes' parameters from the head of the parameter list.

I am implementing a version where the parameters are consumed from the tail end of the parameter list, but the complier has issues inferring the type.

Is there a way to improve this such that the compiler can infer the type correctly?

```
type Arr = readonly unknown[];

function partialCallTail<T extends Arr, U extends Arr, R>(
  f: (...args: [...T, ...U]) => R, ...tailArgs: U
) {
  return (...headArgs: T) => f(...headArgs, ...tailArgs)
}

const foo = (x: string, y: number, z: boolean) => {}

// compiles, but verbose
const foo2: (x: string, y: number) => void = partialCallTail(foo, false)
foo2('a', 2)

const foo1: (x: string) => void = partialCallTail(foo, 2, false)
foo1('a')

// does not compile
partialCallTail(foo, false)('a', 2)
                ~~~

TS2345: Argument of type '(x: string, y: number, z: boolean) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(...args: [...unknown[], boolean]) => void'.
   Types of parameters 'x' and 'args_0' are incompatible.
     Type '[...unknown[], boolean]' is not assignable to type '[x: string, y: number, z: boolean]'.
       Target requires 3 element(s) but source may have fewer.
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgziA2CmB0w4EMBOAKAlAWAFB4BcBPAB1gAIBBVVcgXnNVmQBNxojyBXMAazBAB3MAG0AugG48hUhQBiPYPXLp4atAHMIALnLIwRcZnoA+PQem5iZcgAlmLADzUt5WAA8CsMCwhUaADTkACrIAJbQbp7evv6oZgwufh5ePn4iavBhYABmsLT2rEGZoRFi5AD8dg7kumCwAG75UvhWsiHh0M6orikxftTxyklRqbEiPPxCYMVq2Xm0AEqwEARieOSV5Muro-3k4lv1TagbtdsrBOQAPh0RjjsEZnWN+ZY5igRh4OQkaF-IaAAYUB0FKXTkezS5AUYGAQXBIz60PBjgACmhkABbWBeVAQRxyEwmII7LjQK7I2LLAhcVBgYKyQnE9BnHK6OSzeAETpJXSInoQPCYXSqNQACwcfOqrHRmJxeIJRIRvMFJmMdDMZIp5AA3mcmLT6YwVuSCJZNh84V8fkwIGaxfBJaxpYUnBjUNjcfklSS7tAkurdNqrvrcJtNoa6WByDlHc6WEkuTyIkkcOHyABfPDZ1pW4A2mM5EAgdDuXSrVDZDRBIh1LhYgBG+SCAC9dI2SygwMYO13mDGw5tQJAYAhoCANGXa2305HcdHyARUFxYDnLAB6DfkACq9XcZALsBYbhoIFogklMeAoOr5EEYQI4vIAl+8u9+Lwf1QAOBoPB6DFiAmDoAA5MgoFBAATEEOSAhAsDpngW7kKANCwAWX7-GEgIgtAYKdIBJawfBiFgY2kHkFB6bfr+eEEREREgNBJHQAhIGgcAoFIbgKF7h4h5eCe+SoOe95Xqht5gBo96Ps+oJvp6Co+lhP44X++EAUBQSgSwlEwbGpE8XAVzsio5bkJW1YamYnZjvoyi0ep9FacRVGsexm7bgAIiAKwviAVyCOevCyU+cTIEQ8A5BEeJBCwKwkI+FDNneT4UGhTAFrG55YsgBDwMh26DJF0Wxfkb4QAhfjZEukrkNkCXuOYJ5oJ6nAECAdUUPmhbwJsADKsAUBOMkgFwBAkBNhW4CZJr2jqDAiKBsCUaBORrRooFiGVFL5IBPEod5sBYuAlb5XeTm4QpwWoLwd4PuFCk3tVeC9d8MZXRpXTBFCsSDEEO5-QMgTbCYrIZmZjqaDoBwlFyO5iDZ2xcgm0rBMKoqZCmAaCroO7I4seoGguxqOjj0oE6YsbxlKgrJqqWjprmql0aCTEcZQ+keYhrPOez2nkKBABC3HoAZcFsbzuBffRTE6UC+kgZLnky9h134fLQvedzhlSyB6Zzbd93SSGygiCrsBBMuq47TFe0YLLAtuaBACiSs8UAA) for comment below.

Answer (score 1):

Probably there's a simpler way, but here's a working version:

```
type Arr = readonly unknown[];

type Func = (...args: any[]) => any

type Head<Args extends Arr, Tail extends Arr> = Args extends [...infer Head, ...Tail] ? Head : never;

type Tail<Args extends Arr> = Args extends [unknown, ...infer Rest]
  ? Rest extends [] ? never
  : Rest | Tail<Rest> : never

function partialCallTail<F extends Func, TailArgs extends Tail<Parameters<F>>>(
  f: F, ...tailArgs: TailArgs
) {
  return (...headArgs: Head<Parameters<F>, TailArgs>) => f(...headArgs, ...tailArgs)
}

const foo = (x: string, y: number, z: boolean) => {}

partialCallTail(foo, false)('a', 2)

partialCallTail(foo, 2, false)('a')

// Expected error
partialCallTail(foo, 2, false)(1)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggTnKBeKcIEMAmB7AdgGxCgFdcBrXbAd1wG0BdAbgFgAoN0SKAMVIGNkUABQA6MejgBzAM4AuKOlwgGASmQA%20BUrYdw0ABIZMAHngyoEAB7AIuTNNgIANFAAq6AJb4L12-cdwmihmDlY2dg60YiIeuABmEIiGWC7R7l70UAD8UMmYUPK4EABuiSzsrJzQ6fimUqG%20EQFBjuZhfpGkFNS4qWKxCYgAShDSwPRsUNlQI2M%204f4M00WlcJMFM6PAUAA%20bp61s8CahSWJOqxx-MAeeFBgEjfo%20ADCz-g1xtzzHTz8LjUQj8mp8AAoSdAAWwgNjg0i%206kRQnWcXk3D6ImABxC8kB9TYagA3us0MBiHBcMJogALIw43JGYzguBQmGJeHcdQA7H1dRqJCaOKiMS0rAhDFYrwhFRsAC%20Fz4eDmcWw2EEQks8jGcFikhcIEKxEhACNEi4AF7yY2q-AYXD8zSEqDyioPOBPV7vGpCFXYFxxZ7SCAqIQAcnQoZcACYZa7Hh5nm98B8Dj7VdH-YHg2GI7G2AB6fNQACilkgfBs%20UScGwa1Ybo9SZTXjTfqgUcz%20CDIYAjHnKnoeKrBJ9aNrdS5cEbTXAXNbsLbFPR1GwgA)

The main difference is that we start from inferring the passed function type, then get union of possible tails.

---

If you want to allow providing no/all params for some reason (not a partial anymore), it is simple change in `Tail`:

```
type Tail<Args> = Args extends [unknown, ...infer Rest]
  ? Args | Tail<Rest> : Args
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgziA2CmB0w4EMBOAKAlAWAFB4BcBPAB1gAIBBVVcgXnNVmQBNxojyBXMAazBAB3MAG0AugG48hUhQBiPYPXLp4atAHMIALnLIwRcZnoA%20PQem5iZcgAlmLADzUt5WAA8CsMCwhUaADTkACrIAJbQbp7evv6oZgwufh5ePn4iavBhYABmsLT2rEGZoRFi5AD8dg7kumCwAG75UvhWsiHh0M6oWgn%20rikx6Tz8QmDFatl5tABKsBAEYnjklf1%20AD4dEY5zC2a6SZY5igRh4OQkaKfI0ADCN9ClXXJRqbEKYMBBT0mvQ1tdAAKaGQAFtYF5UBBHHITHD0MtyDldHIJvACJ0krofj0IHhjABvRFMAhcVBgFSZAAWDix1VYjmBqDBEPy0Nh30xuJMxjoZhyqjUNNYSTRGIiSRwuAAvkcTmcKTkQCB0O5dAtUNkNEEiHUuKCAEb5IIAL10BuVKDAmHNluYFKJuBWoEgMAQ0BAGlVOtNUpWJLJFIIqC4sDwstwl1Q1zuDye6CVIEw6AA5MgU0EAExBHI3CCwKVRmP3aCPToJ5U5vMF1MGjPkTOFq5hG4lssRCsgLNV6D55Mp4AppvRlux0vxxNBFMsevZpHVqWWazyZXKJ6OEQarVBMD6o2oIIWt36MQmSxAA)

Comment: Thanks for this.  Unfortunately while this makes the compiler happy for these simple examples, once I started to use it with `Array.filter` some thing goes wrong at runtime.  I'll update the question with a playground link.

Comment: @Matt I've added example how to allow calling with all or without parameters. Regarding `filter` - that's how it works, it will always pass all params, the callback can choose to use them or not. There're no overloads in Javascript, type definitions are erased at compile time and have no effect on runtime behavior.